# How much aluminum was used in the Boeing 727?

Tags: fuselage, weight, boeing-727

What is the **weight** of aluminum used in the Boeing 727 fuselage? Do you know where I can find it? Any manual or site or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be possible to provide a precise number for a question with so many variables. Likely, the amount differed between variants. Without speaking to a materials acquisitions director from Boeing in the 70s and 80s, the precise number is probably not available.

That said, this [airplane scrapyard website](https://www.airplaneboneyards.com/airplane-boneyard-reclamation-disassembly-scrapping.htm) mentions that aluminum accounts for approximately 20% of the weight in a Boeing 747. Going by that same rubric, one might estimate that a 727 would contain approximately 41,900 pounds of aluminum.